# Different results on different printers when printing CSS cm sizes

Tags: css, printing

I am trying to print a box from a web page where the size is defined in cm - when I print to different printers I seem to get different results.

For example, I just printed an example on my home printer where I set it to print at 10cm wide and it printed at 10.5cm but on my work printer it prints at 8.5cm wide. All other settings are the same - same laptop, same browser (Safari on Mac) etc

A customer has tried the same thing this time on a PC running Firefox and Chrome and he also gets a smaller size than intended - in his case he wants the output to be 8.5cm x 5.5cm but it prints much smaller (top is Firefox, bottom is Chrome):

[image]

I don't have the exact sizes and apologies the image is so small (this is what we were sent) but it is clearly not printing to the card size.

The box I am trying to print is set using:

```
#id-card { 
    width: 10cm;
    height: 6cm;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The border is added only so I can accurately measure the printed size - I realise it may cause a slight variance in the width but not to the extremes I am seeing.

Is there anything else which can influence the actual printed size?

Comment: Are you also taking into consideration the things outside of the #id-card, like the @page layout and html & body?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the html and body to the expected print dimensions of the card. You did not share your HTML, so this is just an idea of how to control it.

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: 10cm 6cm;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  html, body {
    width: 100mm;
    height: 60mm;
  }
  #id-card { 
    width: 10cm;
    height: 6cm;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```